# Get the current german time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, time, utc, gmt

I would like to get the currently german time in JavaScript. Normally its GMT+1
but german time consists of the winter time and the summer time. In the summer time we are 1 hour ahead.

```
var now = new Date();
var hour = now.getUTCHours() + 1; // it works, but not by the summer-time
```

Comment: If using a library is feasible then you should look into [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: try this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/11888430/1981678

Comment: IT seems like the way you need to do this is to find a source or a formula that establishes the date that summer starts and ends.

Answer (score 2):

I always recommend using great library for date and time, which is Moment.js. You can achieve required functionality pretty easy. Check this SO thread out for more details: [Moment.js - How To Detect Daylight Savings Time And Add One Day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21918095/moment-js-how-to-detect-daylight-savings-time-and-add-one-day)