# Why I'm getting UTC(+00:00) even I'm runnning my aws lambda at ap-northeast-2 region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm running lambda at region ap-northeast-2

this is part of my code, getting a timestamp for DynamoDB

```py
import datetime
a = datetime.datetime.now().astimezone().replace(microsecond=0).replace(second=0).isoformat()
```

if I run this, I get "2021-12-25T15:33:00+00:00"

while I get "2021-12-26T00:34:00+09:00" on my laptop.

I thought that lambda will return same as mine because I'm at Seoul so does ap-northeast-2 region
is there a reason why I couldn't get my timezone?

Comment: "2021-12-25T15:33:00+00:00" and "2021-12-26T00:33:00+09:00" are the same time.

Comment: @matt I know it's the same time, I was asking why aws's python is giving me +00:00, not +09:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambda instances always use UTC as their time zone, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html under Reserved Environment Variables: `TZ`.

It would be awkward if the time zone switched depending on the region where you run.

Related: [AWS Lambda Timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55384102/aws-lambda-timezone) (the link above came from the comments on that question).